# Erro na comparação com resposta

Tags: php, ajax

Tenho este *JS* abaixo, que incluo ele ao final do meu documento. Ele manda os dados via ajax para um arquivo PHP que responde um texto, no exemplo abaixo **-666** e -**logar**.

Ocorre que não cai na condição certa. Vejo através dos dados retornados e não se encaixa. Começou recentemente, sei que isso não é normal de se ouvir, mas sim, começou a menos de 5 dias da entrega da aplicação.

Vejam:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //enviando form
    $( document ).on( "click", "#bt_send", function() {
                f_submit();
    }); 
    function f_submit(){
        $('#message').html('<center><span style="color:#0091ea;"Processando</span></center>');
        var form_data = {
            email: $('#email').val(),
            senha: $('#senha').val(),
            is_ajax: 1
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data,
            url: 'php/acesso/login.php',
            success: function(response)
            {
                $('#message').html(response);
                switch (response)
                {                
                  case "-logar": 
                       $('#message').html('<span style="color:#00c853;"><center>Bem Vindo. Carregando permissões.</center></span>');
                       window.location = 'painel.php';
                       break;
                  case "-666": 
                       $('#message').html('<span style="color:#dd2c00;"><center>E-mail ou senha incorreto.</center></span>');
                       break;
                  default: 
                       alert(response);
                       break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Bem-vindo Maicon Martins,  você conseguirá melhores respostas se der às pessoas código que elas possam usar para reproduzir o problema. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Faça um console.log(response) na callback de sucesso  e coloque o resultado

Comment: posta o `console.log(response)`